# onEdit Trigger for a specified cell range only

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have written a script to copy a range of cells from a single sheet to a new sheet that will be used to track work, this is working well although only with the trigger for onedit. I would like to modify the script so that it only updates the tracking sheet when the specified range of cells are edited. I believe this can be done with onEdit(e) but I have been unable to figure it out so far.

````
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();//source spreadsheet

  var ts = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/MYSHEET');//target spreadsheet for tracking

  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Report Template");//source sheet

  var targetSheet = ts.getSheetByName("Tracker");//target sheet

  var values = sourceSheet.getRange("H7:I7").getValues();//source sheet cell range to copy to target sheet



  var valuesLength = values.length;

  if (!valuesLength) return;



  var lastRow = targetSheet.getLastRow();

  var requiredRows = lastRow + valuesLength - targetSheet.getMaxRows();

  if (requiredRows > 0) targetSheet.insertRowsAfter(lastRow, requiredRows);



  values[0].push(new Date()); //Add Date to the 2D array.

  targetSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, valuesLength, values[0].length).setValues(values);





}```
````

Answer (score 0):

- You need an `if` statement that evaluates which cells are being edited
- To access the edited cell, you can use the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions) `range`, that returns you the cell that has been edited

### Sample:

```
function onEdit(event){
var cellName = event.range.getA1Notation();
  if(cellName == "A1" || cellName == "A2"){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();//source spreadsheet
    ...
  }
}
```

### UPDATE:

You also have some other minor errors, like e.g. the requiredRows definition.

You full code would look something like the following, whereby you should replace cells `A1` and `A2` through the cells you actually would like to watch:

```
function onEdit(event){
  var cellName = event.range.getA1Notation();
  if(cellName == "A1" || cellName == "A2"){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();//source spreadsheet
    var ts = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/MYSHEET');//target spreadsheet for tracking
    var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Report Template");//source sheet
    var targetSheet = ts.getSheetByName("Tracker");//target sheet
    var values = sourceSheet.getRange("H7:I7").getValues();//source sheet cell range to copy to target sheet
    var valuesLength = values.length;    
    if (!valuesLength) return;
    var lastRow = targetSheet.getLastRow();
    var requiredRows = valuesLength;
    values[0].push(new Date()); //Add Date to the 2D array.
    targetSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, valuesLength, values[0].length).setValues(values);
  }
}
```

**IMPORTANT:**

To use services that require authorization, such as `SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl()`, you need to replace your [simple](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions) `onEdit` trigger through an [installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) one.

Comment: I have tried all day to get this working but I cannot seem to figure it out, all changes I make always fail, I followed your advice and added my original code along with updating the cellName to the cells I am interested in but had no success.

Comment: My Executions errors

You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets at onEdit(Code:5)

Comment: OAuth needs to be modified so I did this

Appsscript.json Manifest

 

```{

  "oauthScopes": [

    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"

  ],

"timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles",

  "dependencies": {

  },

  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER"

}```

Comment: Before the code runs `onEdit`, you need to run it once manually (even if it gives you an error). This will trigger authorization flow and assign the script the necessary scopes (provided you give the permissions).

Comment: I did exactly this and it is still failing with the same error under executions. To test further I created a new sheet and copied the script into it, ran it once, gave permissions and then checked and the executions still have the same issue. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Don't set the scopes in the manifest manually, but allow the script to detect automatically which scopes it needs.

Comment: When I copied the script over I did not copy the manifest so it did set the scopes automatically and for some reason it is still not working and still providing that same error on the executions.

Comment: If you provide me access to a sample sheet (please remove all sensitive private data) I can have a look at it!

Comment: I can provide access to a sample sheet, is there a simple way to send this to you and not post it directly here?

Comment: I would prefer you to provide a dummy sheet that has no private information, so you can share it by posting a publicly accessible link - after all Stackoverflow is a public forum.

Comment: Ok here is a link to a public share of the master sheet with the script. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uGpv6uPYYtCTXnuXbe7DbEUJbEPT23-PgQMZX0Ukrts/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You error comes from the fact that you are using a simple trigger to access a service that requires authorization (`SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl()`), see [restrictions of simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions). Solution: Replace the simple trigger through an [installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) one.

Comment: I have read through the documentation provided regarding simple and installable triggers and I am not sure I fully understand how they work, I did try with the script with this new function. function installableOnEdit(e){ But it only works if you specifically run it through the apps script itself.